# java AES Encryption for a data stream

Tags: android, encryption

I am using AES encryption in my Android app, where the data is coming as stream. Sometime the data stream contains data as big as 8MB. I cannot create a byte array for 8MB in Android, it will kill all other apps for creating such a big heap. So I decided to use byte array buffer and encrypt small chunks of data at a time. But the data is getting corrupted

```
Key key = generateKey();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
c.init(mode, key);
while(all bytes are read){
byte[] encValue = c.update(valueToEnc);
}
```

I even tried calling c.doFinal() on my last chunk but even that didn't help. Can anyone direct me to a good tutorial on how to encrypt or decrypt a stream in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) and/or [CipherOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) instead. Usually these are much easier to use.